# Can't publish scoped NPM package in the private GH registry using GITHUB_TOKEN or PAT

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions, cicd

I'm in a private GitHub repository and I need to publish my scoped packages in `npm.pkg.github.com`.

I haven't created an organization (because what for?) so it's just a private repository representing a monorepo with a scope.

First, I tried to use `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` along with `actions/setup-node@v3` but it didn't work out:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myscope%2fmypackage - Permission permission_denied: The requested installation does not exist.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

Second, I tried to use PAT, but now I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myscope%2fmypackage - Permission permission_denied: create_package
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: What scopes did you give to your PAT? write:packages?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, write and delete.

Comment: Are you following [Working with the npm registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could share the code that you put into the yaml file (GHA itself), that would make possible to give you better help.

So I did such things in both personal account and organization accounts, and found the following rules:

- the packages scope must be the user/org name. like @mycompany/package-name
- when you do setup node it worths to use the scope there, like `scope: '@mycompany'`
- `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` should be enough to do this with some additional permission

Find out our internal registry releaser GHA:

```yaml
name: Publish packages

on:
    workflow_dispatch:
    release:
        types: [created]

jobs:
    publish-github-registry:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
          contents: read
          packages: write
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
              with:
                node-version: 18
                registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
                scope: '@company'
            - run: yarn install
              working-directory: packages/package-path
            - run: yarn build
              working-directory: packages/package-name
            - run: yarn publish packages/package-name --access restricted
              env:
                NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Please note that this is an initial script, thats why I added `working-directory`. It makes no sense (and even antipattern) in proper nx, or turbo monorepos.
The given package will be only privately accessible, thats another thing - you will need to set up `.npmrc` to use it (or push to the public registry ofc).

Comment: Then this is the thing: "scope must be the user/org name" as I don't have an org and my scope doesn't equal my username. I failed to find this info in the docs. How did you figure that out?

Comment: Im sorry to say, but i cannot clearly remember. Here is the official documentation for GH Registry, this mentions it multiple times, but i didnt find a clear reference.

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#publishing-a-package

I have to mention the fact, that the process took at least 2 weeks to figure everything out.

Comment: Thanks one more time @kfarkas! After I registered an organization with the name of my scope, it started working. (I had to change the name of the scope tho: finding a free org name was quite a task!)